# How to change data color in UI Grid Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

|number | 1 3 4|

For example , I need to show "1" as red , "3" as green . they are in the same cell . i know i can use cell class to change the whole data color in one cell . but that 's not what i want .

Could you please give me some clues to work it out ? or is this any other way to do this ,like Angular UI or using other libraries .

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to read [how to ask a good question(http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this isn't so much a ui-grid thing, as being a general question of how you render data with in angular colours.

I would probably do this with a custom cellTemplate, and some sort of ng-style.  The question is how your data is arriving in the cell - so are the `1 3 4` coming from the cell value, or do you have something else going on?

Assuming that they are in the cell value, then you'd probably need something like

```
<div ng-style="grid.appScope.setStyle(grid.appScope.left(COL_FIELD)>grid.appScope.left(COL_FIELD)</div>
<div ng-style="grid.appScope.setStyle(grid.appScope.mid(COL_FIELD)>grid.appScope.mid(COL_FIELD)</div>
<div ng-style="grid.appScope.setStyle(grid.appScope.right(COL_FIELD)>grid.appScope.right(COL_FIELD)</div>
```

Where 
- `setStyle` is a function on your scope that takes in a number and decides what style to apply to it 
- `left` gets the leftmost number from your data
- `mid` gets the middle number from your data
- `right` gets the rightmost number from your data

If your input structures are different then there are other ways to use cellTemplates to get the result you want.

EDIT: Based on the further information, I think you'll want to render your string as html, and then parse that html into the cell.  I think this is then more a broader question of "how can angularJS render arbitrary HTML for me", and the answer may be ng-bind-html, although I don't know much about it.  In theory that would let you create your markup in html, then bind that resulting markup into the cell by using `ng-bind-html='COL_FIELD'` in the cellTemplate.

Comment: Hi . Thanks PauIL , It received data from Rest Api , Basically i want to show the difference  between two rows. i am not sure how many stuff in one cell .but it supposed to be a list . i plan to show stuff(new) as green . item (deleted) as red .

Comment: OK, so you're parsing the string to do a diff, and highlighting different parts of the string.  I think this approach I suggested won't work because you'll need a differing number of divs or spans depending on what your result looks like.

Comment: Hey , i solved it by imbedding divs into cellTemplates, actually  this 's the same idea with you . thanks ! :)